# mongoose push nested subdocument array of objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How would I push some comment for each sub_section inside the Comments array with mongoose.
please see picture

```
_id:objected('834838959384'),
sections:[
  {
    title:"title of post", 
    sub_section:[
    {id:objected('5894389'), comments[{author:"jP", text:"lorem" }, ]}
    

]}
```

Comment: Could you please give more details about what you want to achieve ? What will be your collection before and after the operation ? Thank you.

Comment: In want to push a new user comment inside the comments array; the comment array should have a second Item added to it after the operation

Comment: how are you going to find the sections by title or id ? or section will always be one ?

Comment: How do you want to select the section and the sub_section ?

Comment: I want to select by id

Answer (score 0):

Based on informations you gave, you can do something like this :

```js
UserModel.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: ObjectId("834838959384") }, {
  $push: { "sections.$[sec].sub_section.$[subsec].comments": commentToAdd }
}, {
  arrayFilters: [ { "sec.title": "title of post" }, { "subsec.id": ObjectId("5894389") } ]
}, function (err, user) {  });
```